# Android - JSON stored list contains objects that revert to superclass when app is exited, reopened

Tags: java, android, json, gson, persistent

I have an `ArrayList <GeneralTemplate> items`

Throughout my program, I am adding Routines which are subclasses of GeneralTemplate i.e `items.add(new Routine("Test"));` and all is well.

Most importantly, I can do the following.. `Routine myRoutine = items.get(position);`

I am saving this big list of items in a special data object in JSON using Google's GSON library. I believe this may be the problem.

This data object contains the `ArrayList <GeneralTemplate> items`. During my program, I can see that the routines stored in the items list are indeed `Routine` objects. I then save it using the code below. I have followed this process with the debugger and when I setRoutineList, the Routine objects are maintained without problem.

```
// Global save String method
public static void save()
{
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    RoutineData tempSaveObject = new RoutineData();
    tempSaveObject.setRoutineList(routineList);

    String routineListInJSON = gson.toJson(tempSaveObject);

    editor.putString(ROUTINE_LIST, routineListInJSON).commit();
}
```

The problem occurs when I restart the app and retreive the data. All of the items in the list revert to `GeneralTemplate` objects and cannot be cast back to `Routine` via `Routine routine = (Routine) items.get(position)` -> `ClassCastException` (Code for loading below)

```
    // Get a global sharedPreferences object that can be used amongst Activities
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedPreferences.contains(ROUTINE_LIST))
    {
        String routineListJSON = sharedPreferences.getString(ROUTINE_LIST, null);
        routineDataObject = gson.fromJson(routineListJSON, RoutineData.class);

        routineList = routineDataObject.getRoutineList();
    }
    else
    {
        routineList = new ArrayList<GeneralTemplate>();     
    }
```

Therefore, I can't access specific methods and variables because I cant regain the subclass context. There are several other instances of this problem, so if there is any good solution to this that you good folks knowledge, it would help a lot.

Thanks!

SORTED:

Genson JSON library.

https://code.google.com/p/genson/downloads/detail?name=genson-0.94.jar&can=2&q=

Made things so much easier, no need for custom serializers/deserializers. Took care of all the in depth polymorphism stuff by default.

Implemented as shown in Eugen's answer

Comment: Please show how you reload.

Comment: Ah yes, pretty key that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you have a list of GeneralTemplate, while serializing Gson knows the concrete type of each element in the list but during deserialization Gson doesn't know into which type to deserialize (as it is a list of GeneralTemplate).

I am not sure but it looks like they have some contrib (not part of Gson) that allows to add type information in the serialized stream, this allows Gson to deserialize back into the right type.

You could also try out [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) library, handling polymorphic types is supported out of the box. It has the features provided by Gson and some others too. Here is how you can achieve it:

```
// first configure your Genson instance to enable polymorphic types support and  
// serialization based on concrete types
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder()
                            .setWithClassMetadata(true)
                            .setUseRuntimeTypeForSerialization(true)
                            .create();

// and now just use it to serialize/deser
String json = genson.serialize(routineData);
RoutineData data = genson.deserialize(json, RoutineData.class);
```

**EDIT**
Problem solved. The Routine class had no default constructor. Putting @JsonProperty("name") on the ctr parameter and using gensons previous configuration solved the problem.

Comment: This is a good answer, but if you don't want to use other libraries, you could also add a private member to GeneralTemplate which contains the class name as string.  This will obviously serialise and deserialise without issue.  You can then use ClassForName() when you deserialise your JSON to create new instances of the correct type.  The problem you have is that as eugen says, your deserialised  type with always be the base class.

Comment: In the solution you describe he will have to implement a custom deserializer for all polymorphic types he needs to handle. It sounds a bit as too much work for something that should be handled by a lib :/

Comment: Hmmm, Genson looks pretty handy. Is there anyway to download it as a .jar like GSON? Only recently got Git up and running, not very familiar with it yet

Comment: @mgibson great you like it :) yeah sure if you use maven use the dependency from here http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted#Download, if you just want to dl the jar you can find it here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.owlike/genson/0.94 (you have a download link there)

Comment: @mgibson by the way you should not get source code for libs and package it your self, as the code in the trunk is not matching the released version

Comment: Thanks! Not on Maven yet either :P But this does look promising, if it is as simple as you mentioned, I will be a very happy man! Cheers, I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: @mgibson cool waiting towards your feedback :) if you have questions on genson you can read the wiki and use its google group to ask for help

Comment: Hmm so on first attempt implementing it as you did I am getting a `TransformationException`..  `routineDataObject = genson.deserialize(routineListJSON, RoutineData.class);
    routineList = routineDataObject.getRoutineList();` Getting it from the deserialize line. Initialized it just as you did and saved it like this.. `String routineListInJSON;
   routineListInJSON = genson.serialize(tempSaveObject);
   
   editor.putString(ROUTINE_LIST, routineListInJSON).commit();` I will have a play around with it and check out those resources - any ideas yourself though would also be well received! :P